# Can I create a Google Analytics destination URL goal funnel that measures if page X is visited before page Y with any amount of intermediary pages?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking

I only care if the user visits page X **before** page Y. I do not care if their path looks like page X -> page Z -> page W -> page Y **or** page X-> page Y. Both are considered conversions for me. I am curious if just defining a required first step as page X and the destination URL as page Y, if that will properly measure this?

I am okay with **any** amount of intermediary pages (0,1,2,...,N). I simply want to know if a user has visited page X and page Y in the same session and they have visited page X **before** page Y. Thank you!

Comment: I know that if you have intermediary steps in your funnel that the user bypasses, GA still counts the funnel and backfills the intermediary steps.  I'm not sure what happens if the user visits arbitrary pages that aren't part of your funnel inbetween.

Comment: You'll likely want to create a custom sequence segment
https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/04/04/more-accurate-conversion-data-sequence-segments/